# Run script on shell login for all users

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, bash, ssh

I have a script named "als" that parses the aliases in a user's `.bashrc` file that I'd like to run for any user logging in via SSH.

This should display similar to a Message of the day (MOTD) banner. MOTD banners are static data though.

Here's the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
echo Your aliases:
echo \(from ~/.bashrc\)
echo
cat .bashrc | egrep 'alias.+\=' | tr -s [:space:] | sed 's_^ alias_alias_' | sed 's_alias__' | sort | sed 's_=_\t\t_' | sed 's_^ __'
```

It works if I append ./als to my `~/.profile` file, but this only executes for me. Again, I'd like this to run for all users on shell login

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could save your script in `/etc/profile.d/als.sh`. According to Ubuntu [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-profile.d.2BAC8.2A.sh) manual:

> Files with the .sh extension in the /etc/profile.d directory get
>   executed whenever a bash login shell is entered (e.g. when logging in
>   from the console or over ssh), as well as by the DisplayManager when
>   the desktop session loads.

You should also modify relative path with absolute path:

```
 cat /home/$USER/.bashrc | egrep 'alias.+\=' | tr -s [:space:] | sed 's_^ alias_alias_' | sed 's_alias__' | sort | sed 's_=_\t\t_' | sed 's_^ __'
```

And this should works for all users.

Comment: This does work. Thank you. That's exactly what I was after. I was going to nail down the absolute path when I found out how to run for all shell logins.

Comment: It worked for every logged user except *root*. How can I do this for the root user?

Comment: @Rhuan Karlus do you mean when you run commands with sudo? In this case, you shoud read "sudo caveat" paragraph in the link posted above

Comment: That's exactly what I needed @Lety !! Thank you very much.