# Script to notify system services status on login

Tags: bash, scripts, python, systemd

I'd like to get a script (bash or python) running that prints in a  simple format the state of all system services when a user logs in.

```
service --status-all
```

The above command outputs them all in a list like so

```
[+] servicename
[?] servicename
[-] servicename
```

When a user logs in the script should provide a human readable message about the services that are running.

I understand there may be utilities to do this but I want to learn some more about scripting and how should a thing can be done.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Human-readable message of what form? Without knowing what you want to output, how can we help you? Is "some services are running" an acceptable output?

Comment: I would say something like this:

> The following services are running 

> ntp, rsync, ssh, etc...

Comment: Please know what you want and decide on it. It appears you haven't taught things through...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want output like:

```
The following services are running: ntp, rsync, ssh,
```

You can use `awk` to transform the output of `service --status-all`:

```
$ service --status-all | awk '/+/{printf "%s", sep " " $NF; sep=","}'
 acpid, alsa-utils, apache-htcacheclean, apache2, apparmor, apport, atd, avahi-daemon, cron, cups-browsed, dbus, grub-common, irqbalance, keyboard-setup, kmod, lightdm, network-manager, networking, ondemand, procps, rc.local, resolvconf, rsyslog, speech-dispatcher, ssh, udev, ufw, urandom, whoopsie
```

So your script would look like:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
printf "The following services are running: " 
service --status-all | awk '/+/{printf "%s", sep " " $NF; sep=","}'
echo
```

The `awk` command is simple:

- `/+/` matches lines with `+` in it. Normally, `+` would mean one or more of the preceding expression. But, by itself, `+` means just `+`. Awk runs the following `{...}` block if this pattern matches.
- `printf "%s" sep " " $NF` prints the contents of the variable `sep`, followed by a space, and followed by the last field of the line (`NF` is the number of fields, and `$x` is the contents of field no. x).
- `sep` is empty at first, so the first service to be printed has just a space before it. Now I set `sep=","`, so the next line onwards, we have a `,`.
- This doesn't print a newline, so I use a simple `echo` at the end to print one.

Now use something like this: [Run script on shell login for all users](https://askubuntu.com/q/548101/158442) to run the script on login.

Comment: Thank you very much @muru. This is exactly what I needed! I have been delving into awk recently so this is even better :)