# The correct place to put scripts for every logged user including ROOT

Tags: bash, scripts, automation, sh

I'm looking for the correct place to hold scripts to run for all users including the **root** user.

I know that adding content to the `/etc/profile` file or creating scripts into the `/etc/profile.d/` folder would work for any logged user, but I want these scripts to run for the root user too.

Where do I need to put them?

Comment: AFAIK files in `/etc/profile.d` will be sourced for the `root` user in the same circumstances as for any other user: when the user invokes a Bourne-compatible login shell. In what way exactly are they not working?

Comment: You want to execute the scripts when the user logs into the system or let the user have them available to run bu themselves ? Also steeldriver is correct, and clarification on what exactly isnt working and if there are particular errors would be helpful

Comment: Guys, you didn't understand the problem here, I want to execute commands login in with `sudo -s` too. In this case, the whole environment is reset, but I've found out a way to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with some experts, specifically in this question: [Run script on shell login for all users](https://askubuntu.com/q/548101/473468) someone told me to read the `sudo caveat` section of the link below:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#sudo_caveat

And here's the answer:

```
sudo caveat

Any variables added to these locations will not be reflected when invoking them
with a sudo command, as sudo has a default policy of resetting the Environment and 
setting a secure path (this behavior is defined in /etc/sudoers). As a workaround,
you can use sudo su that will provide a shell with root privileges but retaining
any modified PATH variables. Alternatively you can setup sudo not to reset certain
environment variables by adding some explicit environment settings to keep in
/etc/sudoers:
```

Run `sudo visudo` and add the following to the bottom:

**`Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy SOMEOTHERVARIABLES ANOTHERVARIABLE ETC"`**